# Multiple functions on knockout view model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Is it possible to add multiple functions to a knockout view model? When I use:

```
var viewModel = {
    filters: ko.observableArray([]),
    addFilter: function() {
        // some code
    }
};
```

it works fine, as soon as I add another method:

```
var viewModel = {
    filters: ko.observableArray([]),
    addFilter: function() {
        // some code
    },
    copyFilter: function() {
        // some code
    }
};
```

everything stops working. I also tried to extend the samples on the knockout website to use multiple functions, but the same thing happened to them too.

So does anyone know how to add multiple functions to the view model?

Edit: Probably should have mentioned, the error im getting is 'copyFilter is undefined', however it most definitely isn't

Comment: This code is fine.  You problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: No I dont think so, if you take a look at alone of the samples and add another function to its view model it stops working too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KO doesn't care if your view model has multiple functions.

Your problem exists somewhere else, perhaps inside the functions themselves. Check your browser's output for javascript errors. Also try making those functions empty functions, just to verify it's a javascript error inside those functions.

Comment: The problem was with where I was trying to call the function. Apparently you can't bind to functions on the view model within a template

Comment: Erm, you can bind to functions on the VM within a KO template. You just have to be aware of the context within the template. If you have a problem with that, I suggest asking a new question, I can help you out.

Comment: Hi, if I'm using rails 3 which uses asset pipeline to combine all
Javascripts, does that mean I can have only one view model for my entire application. If not, how do I specify which view model is binded with which view? In the tutorial code, it looks like 1 view model is bound per page, but that doesnt work in rails since all JS are loaded upon first page load.